# Jquery dynamic division creation

Tags: jquery

I have the following function, i have a results div in my page and i want to dynamically add new div with some text in it, the first .append works and the div gets created but the second append doesn't work and no text gets appended to it. Can anyone tell me why?

```
$.getJSON(docTypeQueryURL + "id=" + doctype, function (data) {
  var div = data.TYPE_ID;
  var resultsDiv='#results';
  var divid = "'#" + div + "'";
  $(resultsDiv).append("<div id='" + div + "'><strong>" + div + "</strong></div>");
  $(divid).append("<p>" + xyzz + "</p>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing `xyzz` and `data.TYPE_ID` are defined and correct, you have to replace

```
var divid = "'#" + div + "'";
```

with

```
var divid = "#" + div;
```

Comment: In addition to what @dystroy said, there's really no need to define var resultsDiv (at least in the current scenario). Remove that line and change $(resultsDiv) to $('#results')

Answer (score 0):

Your `divid` is having an extra `single quote`. Remove it

```
var divid = "#" + div;
```

Also you don't have to use # with your divid. It seems like you are using it as we see in jQuery. See the updated code. That is required only while writing selectors

```
$.getJSON(docTypeQueryURL + "id=" + doctype, function (data) {
  var div = data.TYPE_ID;
  var resultsDiv='#results';
  var divid = div;
  $(resultsDiv).append("<div id='" + div + "'><strong>" + div + "</strong></div>");
  $(divid).append("<p>" + xyzz + "</p>");
});
```